# map a metrics in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Give a df as

```
index  x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4 x_5
  0    50   60   70   30   20
  1    10   20   30   40   50
  2    10   20   20   20   20
```

I have a mapping that maps each row to the corresponding column in df.

mapping df is

```
index  x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4 x_5
  0    1     3   4   1   2
  1    2     2   2   3   5
  2    4     1   1   5   2
```

I want to create a mapped df

Desired output

```
index  x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4 x_5
  0    50    70   30   50  60
  1    20    20   20   30   50
  2    20    10   20   20   20
```

Comment: There are already some answers, but editting the df with unique values would help to understand the output a bit faster and secure that the mapping from the answers is indeed correct and not some missmatch of a double occuring value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

late to the game but an alternative using numpy?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[50, 60, 70, 30, 20],
                   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                   [10, 20, 20, 20, 20]])

map_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 4, 1, 2],
                       [2, 2, 2, 3, 5],
                       [4, 1, 1, 5, 2]])

np.take_along_axis(np.array(df),np.array(map_df)-1,1)
```

```
array([[50, 70, 30, 50, 60],
       [20, 20, 20, 30, 50],
       [20, 10, 10, 20, 20]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use second dataframe rows as indices of first dataframe rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[50, 60, 70, 30, 20],
                   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                   [10, 20, 20, 20, 20]])

map_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 4, 1, 2],
                       [2, 2, 2, 3, 5],
                       [4, 1, 1, 5, 2]])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i][map_df.iloc[i] - 1]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0  50  70  30  50  60
1  20  20  20  30  50
2  20  10  10  20  20
```

EDIT:
Solution without loop:

```py
df.join(map, rsuffix='map').apply(lambda row: pd.Series(np.array(row[:5])[row[5:] - 1]).transpose(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution. Still, I was hopping we don't need to use a for loop. I fully underestand the logic, but it gives me an error. I am using the last version of pandas. ImportError: cannot import name 'find_stack_level' from 'pandas.util._exceptions'

Comment: `apply` is equivalent to using a loop

Comment: this first solution indeed worked. The second one gives this error "ValueError: Suffixes not supported when joining multiple DataFrames"

Comment: Internaly you always need some kind of loop to go through the mask and data frame. But with apply we can do it on a lower level compared to the high level for-loop from the above snipplet.

Comment: @Daraan `apply` is actually often slower than a python loop

Comment: Can you tell if the difference comes from the the slower execution of the function or the loop process?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some `transpose + replace` hack

```
mapping_df.astype(str).radd('x_').T.replace(df.T).T
```

---

```
       x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4  x_5
index                         
0       50   70   30   50   60
1       20   20   20   30   50
2       20   10   10   20   20
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it does not the right output for me. It generates X_1, X_2, ..., X_5 on each row.

Comment: Why did you capitalize the `x`? @user2512443

Comment: Generic method: `map_df.T.replace(df.rename(columns={k:i+1 for i,k in enumerate(df.columns)}).T).T`